# Is the flow same in parallel pipes feeding into a water container?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, piping

I have 2 questions.
I am aware that the headloss is the same in all intakes into a water container.

My question is, is this illustration correct that the flow is different for different outlets?
[image]

And when you calculate the headloss for this system, how do you go to calculate the splits?
As 1 pipe which has the surface of the 2 pipes or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: related question: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40709/how-do-you-determine-flow-distribution-at-a-dividing-t-junction/40714#40714

Comment: also look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_network_analysis

Comment: re. the sketches: Is the view from the side, top down or what?

Comment: From top down. It is a swimming pool to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Diagram A is correct.

There are several piping head loss methods, but a very common one is to apply equivalent feet for Tees and elbows.  [Here's one example](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/pvc-pipes-equivalent-length-fittings-d_801.html)  You would then change the length of the pipes to make them all equivalently equal.

Comment: how do the parapel pipes fit into the equation :D

Comment: @Sangoku all the pipes need to have the same equivalent length

Comment: this ignores the pressure at the pipe ends - one is far lower, that will have an effect. equivalent lengths ignores different flowrates in the different pipe segments.

Comment: @mart, yes, if there are height differences.  The lack of h on the diagram indicates to me a plan view.